# How to ensure PHP curl fully downloads pdf and pdftk command to skip damaged pdfs when merging

Tags: php, pdftk

Currently I have a php scrip that downloads like 50+ pdfs and merges them. But sometimes when downloading it does not download a pdf fully thus it is damaged. When executing the merging command using pdftk it throws exception because of damaged pdfs.

I am using curl to download the pdfs, is it possible to have a check to ensure that the file is fully downloaded before downloading the next one? Or is it possible for pdftk to merge all files skipping the damaged ones?

Below is the code:

Downloading:

```
$fp = fopen($pathS, 'w');
         
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$urlS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Merging:

```
"C:\Program Files\PDF Labs\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" 1.pdf...0.pdf cat output %mydate%.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

I can ensure that a pdf is fully downloaded before proceeding to download the next one.